# Which date is first using DateTime php

Tags: php, date, datetime

I am using the DateTime function and want to find out if a date stored in the database has been passed or is yet to happen.

This is for a banlist.

Currently I attempted to use the -> diff function to get the difference only now realising that it produces an absolute value.

e.g. if the end date for the ban is 16/02/2016 or 20/02/2016 the difference will always be 2 days.

How can I test two dates and see if the date has passed using DateTime?

code I have used and failed with:

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT start, end, length FROM banlist WHERE user_id = ? AND username = ? AND user_email = ?")) {
    $stmt->bind_param('iss', $user_id, $username, $email);

    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($start, $end, $length);
    $stmt->fetch();

    if($stmt->num_rows != 0) {
        if($length == "inf") {
            return 'Indefinitely';
            $stmt->close();
        }
        else {
            $startDate = new DateTime($start);
            $endDate = new DateTime($end);
            $diff=$now->diff($endDate);
            $seconds = $diff->format('%s');
            $mins = $diff->format('%i');
            $hours = $diff->format('%h');
            $days = $diff->format('%d');
            $months = $diff->format('%m');
            $years = $diff->format('%y');

            if($seconds > 0 || $mins > 0 || $hours > 0 || $days > 0 || $months > 0 || $years > 0) {
                return 'for ' . $length .', starting ' . $startDate->format('d/m/Y') . ' at ' . $startDate->format('H:i:s') . ' and ending on ' . $endDate->format('d/m/Y') . ' at ' .$endDate->format('H:i:s');
                $stmt->close();
            }
            else {
                return 'You haven\'t been banned. Please email an admin for assisstance';
                $stmt->close();
            }
        }       
    }
    else {
        return 'You haven\'t been banned. Please email an admin for assisstance';
        $stmt->close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try and use the difference in seconds instead, between now and the ban end date.

```
// assuming $endDate and $now are DateTime objects
$diff = $endDate->getTimestamp() - $now->getTimestamp();
if ($diff > 0) {
    // user is still banned
}
```

Comment: Worked a treat. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use strtotime instead. It returns the Date in seconds, so if the difference is greater than zero, the first date ($end) is grater than the second one ("now"):

```
echo ((strtotime($end) - strtotime("now") >= 0) ? "banned" : "not banned";
```